# Splunk - "grandparent from process and parent process"

Tags: splunk, spl

In my data I have process and parent process. As an example, I can get process id and parent process id for "calc.exe". Now I also want to be able to get "grandparent", ie the parent process for calc.exe's parent process.

```
index=data process=calc.exe
| table process_id parent_process_id grand_parent_id
```

Since I am new to SPL, I have a bit of a hard time understanding how to design a query.

Comment: What do your events look like?

Answer (score 1):

One possible *major* issue you could have is that process IDs get reused *all the time* - so even if you know the ID of what spawned your current process, you *may not* actually be able to find the process that spawned *that* process

If you're OK with that, and you have a pretty definite time window within which you think all of this has happened...something like this should work:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp process="calc.exe" process_id=* parent_process_id=*
| join parent_process_id
    [ | search index=ndx sourcetype=srctp process=* process_id=* parent_process_id=*
    | stats count by process_id process parent_process_id
    | rename parent_process_id as grandparent_process_id process as spawn_process
    | rename process_id as parent_process_id
    | fields - count ]
| table process process_id parent_process_id spawn_process grandparent_process_id
```

*Normally*, you want to avoid the use of [`join`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/join) as much as possible (it's expensive to run, and there are some limitations that may be unacceptable ... depending on your environment and use cases). But sometimes it's the best way to get what you're looking for.

And it *may* be faster to invert the search (run the SPL that finds the `grandparent_process_id` outside, and the one that finds your specific `process_id` and `parent_process_id` as the inner search).

Answer (score 0):

None of the OSs I know have a concept of a "grandparent" process so you won't get that information in one go.  You'll need to find the parent of a process and then find the parent of the parent.  That can be in SPL using a subsearch.

Subsearches run first and the result then becomes part of the main search.  We'll use a subsearch to find calc.exe's parent and return it to the main search as a process_id to find.  The parent_process_id that results will be the "grandparent".

```
index=data 
  [ index=data process=calc.exe
  | fields parent_process_id
  | rename parent_process_id as process_id
  | format ]
| table process_id parent_process_id
```

A side effect of this is the process_id of calc.exe is lost.

Comment: Thanks!

You are certainly right that there is no OS that uses the term grandparent.

What I want to achieve is to follow the process one step further to get a better idea of what is happening.

Is there any possibility to see process id for calc.exe as well? So a table that would look like this:

| table process_id parent_process_id grand_parent_id